# flask send_from_directory within a file representation

Tags: python, flask

Hi I currently have a flask app that shows files and their details, now I want flask to also allow file downloads from the page of the represented file

I tried a couple things including send_from_directory() which didn't work. So my question is how can I add a working download link to the page?

```
@app.route('/browser/<path:urlFilePath>')
def browser(urlFilePath):
    nestedFilePath = os.path.join(FILE_SYSTEM_ROOT, urlFilePath)
    if os.path.isdir(nestedFilePath):
        itemList = os.listdir(nestedFilePath)
        fileProperties = {"filepath": nestedFilePath}
        if not urlFilePath.startswith("/"):
            urlFilePath = "/" + urlFilePath
        return render_template('browse.html', urlFilePath=urlFilePath, itemList=itemList)
    if os.path.isfile(nestedFilePath):
        fileProperties = {"filepath": nestedFilePath}
        sbuf = os.fstat(os.open(nestedFilePath, os.O_RDONLY)) #Opening the file and getting metadata
        fileProperties['type'] = stat.S_IFMT(sbuf.st_mode) 
        fileProperties['mode'] = stat.S_IMODE(sbuf.st_mode) 
        fileProperties['mtime'] = sbuf.st_mtime 
        fileProperties['size'] = sbuf.st_size 
        if not urlFilePath.startswith("/"):
            urlFilePath = "/" + urlFilePath
        return render_template('file.html', currentFile=nestedFilePath, fileProperties=fileProperties)
    return 'something bad happened'

@app.route('/downloads/<path:filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download(filename):
    uploads = os.path.join(current_app.root_path, app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    return send_from_directory(directory=uploads, filename=filename)
```

And with the following HTML

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block header %}
<h1>{% block title %}Filebrowser{% endblock %}</h1>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <p>Current file: {{ currentFile }}</p>
    <p>
        <table>
            {% for key, value in fileProperties.items() %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ key }}</td>
                <td>{{ value }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <a href="{{ url_for('downloads', ['image_name']) }}">File</a>
            </tr>

            {% endfor %}


        </table>
    </p>
    {% endblock %}
```

I want the download link on that page to work for the {{ currentFile }} can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the link to the file in your `file.html` template should probably go *outside* the `for` loop -- otherwise, the link will appear multiple times which is probably not what you want.

Secondly, based on your `/downloads` route, your call to `url_for` for the download link doesn't match up. It should be:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('download', filename=currentFile) }}">File</a>
```

You need to supply the `filename` as an argument so that the flask server can match it to the route & in `url_for`, you need to supply the name of the *function* - which in this case is `download` instead of `downloads`.

Lastly, your `/browser` route prepends the subdirectory to the filename - so when you pass `currentFile` to the HTML template, it will contain the directory prefix -- which you will want to strip, otherwise your link wouldn't work. The file download would then work since in your `/downloads` route, you prefix the `filename` with the directory anyway. Hence, when you render the HTML template, use `os.path.basename()` to obtain the filename without the directory, i.e.

```
return render_template('file.html', currentFile=os.path.basename(nestedFilePath), fileProperties=fileProperties)
```

Comment: this seems to be almost right, the only issue on the output is  this  uploads = os.path.join(current_app.root_path, app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
KeyError: 'UPLOAD_FOLDER'
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2021 16:39:10] "GET /uploads/images/rauc/testfile HTTP/1.1" 500 - the directory does excist, tho so python/flask isn't listing it correctly.

Comment: That error arises from elsewhere in your code. The `UPLOAD_FOLDER` key is missing, which means it hasn't been set correctly in the `app.config` dict - could be a typo somewhere. Make sure its being [set](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#configuration-basics).

Comment: I tried to verify the key error how ever the function right above the download function uses the same flag and app config, yet it still breaks. If I use other flags I get a 404 


 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jan/2021 11:15:44] "GET /uploads/images/rauc/testfile HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: @joeri this post is dated now. You need to post a new question with an updated version of your code, specifying what the new issue(s) are.